# iOS search bar animation fade up in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uisearchbar

I have a search bar added into view controller using this code.

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, MAINSCREEN.size.width, self.searchBar.frame.size.height)];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;

self.searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];

self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64 + self.searchBar.frame.size.height, MAINSCREEN.size.width, MAINSCREEN.size.height)];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

I have to add search bar and table view into view programmatically because I want search bar always stick at the top of table view, so I have used these code.

Unfortunately, there is a problem that, search bar doesn't animated when I fixed the position with `CGRectMake` so I must create my own animation to handle those issue with this code.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*)searchBar {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.55f
                                       delay:0
                      usingSpringWithDamping:500.0f
                       initialSpringVelocity:0
                                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration
                                  animations:^{
                                      self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, MAINSCREEN.size.width, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
                                  }
                                  completion:nil];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f
                          delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:500.0f
          initialSpringVelocity:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, MAINSCREEN.size.width, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

But its movement look kind of stupid when shadow and object have too much different, I have captured a gif image for present that in slow motion.

[image]

**So how can I adjust my search bar's animation for the right way to make it runs extractly same with shadow and navigation bar?.**

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you get the solution ?

Comment: @OmkarJadhav Not yet Omkar, I've been waiting too long and nobody has answer, you may want to vote my answer for get another attention.

Comment: Any idea on how the Google Search app search bar fade in works ? I am looking for that ...

Comment: @OmkarJadhav I've been searching for weeks but not found any solution. The main problem is, I wanted to keep search bar always on top of the screen, but animation  goes wrong.

Comment: @vietnguyen09 is your issue resolved?

Comment: @AnuragSharma Unfortunately, it's not solved yet

Comment: Can you provide a very small demo project?

Comment: @macmoonshine What part do you unclear? I will grab my code and update in my question.

Comment: It's not unclear, but I could play around with the code for testing.